# After getting a Mac, how to install Lion again on another partition?

Tags: macos, dual-boot, multi-boot

After getting a Mac with Lion and creating a partition to install Lion again (to have different versions of Xcode and Xcode beta on different partitions), how can Lion be installed on the new partition?  (Since Lion doesn't have an installation disc).

(update: the Mac already has Lion and so in App Store, it doesn't list Lion as "purchased" but need to pay $29.99 for it)

Answer (score 1):

I usually just use a [disk cloning app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/20228/2220) like [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/) to duplicate my existing Lion install to the other partition. Then you can boot into your new partition and install the Xcode beta.

This method is nice because it moves all of your documents and settings along with the OS so you don't have to use Migration Assistant after installing on the new partition. It's also convenient if you don't have the original Lion installer.

Answer (score 1):

I've just done what you're looking for: Install Lion on another partition. The steps follow.

1. Locate the Lion Installer that you previously downloaded (assuming
   you have it at a backup drive somewhere). Not a problem if you don't
   have it backed up, just launch the Mac AppStore on any Mac (that is
   connected to the partition), find the Purchased and re-download the
   Lion Installer and save it to the partition (the partition has to be
   formatted as Mac OSX compatible i.e not FAT).
2. When the download is completed, launch the Lion Installer.app from
   the partition. Follow the on-screen instructions.

Have fun with Xcode.

Comment: the Mac already came with Lion, so I am wondering where to find the "installation image" from it

Comment: If your Mac was pre-installed with Lion, you should read http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718